# Understanding expanding trig identities

Tags: trigonometry

I already have the answer, but I am trying to figure out why because it's not making much sense. Or maybe my professor misspoke I am not sure.

I have $\sin^5x $ and I am trying to express it in terms containing only first powers of sine and cosine.

Expanding into:

$\sin x\cdot \sin^2x\cdot \sin^2x $

and further:

$\sin x(\frac{1-\cos2x}{2})(\frac{1+\cos2x}{2}) $

And this is the point where I get a little confused. I don't recall any identity saying that $\sin^2x+ \sin^2x $ = $\ (\frac{1-\cos2x}{2})(\frac{1+\cos2x}{2}) $

Anyways the answer is: $\ \frac{\sin x-\sin^2 x\cos 2x + \sin x\cos^2 (2x)}{4} $ But I'm not quite sure how to get there. I figured I would post the answer so people wouldn't think that this is homework, this is for my own understanding.

Comment: Are you sure that is the answer? Also, did you mean $sin^2x +  sin^2x=(\frac{1-cos2x}{2})+(\frac{1-cos2x}{2})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sin^2 x = \frac{1 -\cos(2x)}{2}$, $$\sin^5 x = \sin x \cdot \left(\frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}\right)^2 = \sin x \cdot \frac{1 - 2\cos(2x) +\cos^2(2x)}{4} = \frac{\sin x - 2\sin x \cos(2x) + \sin x \cos^2(2x)}{4}.$$

Since $\cos^2(2x) = \frac{1 + \cos(4x)}{2}$,

\begin{align}\sin x - 2\sin x \cos(2x) + \sin x \cos^2(2x) &= \sin x - 2\sin x \cos(2x) + \frac{1}{2}\sin x + \frac{1}{2}\sin x \cos(4x)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\sin x - 2\sin x \cos(2x) + \frac{1}{2}\sin x \cos(4x).
\end{align}

Therefore

$$\sin^5 x = \frac{3}{8}\sin x - \frac{1}{2}\sin x \cos(2x) + \frac{1}{8}\sin x \cos(4x).$$

Note: The answer you had written does not equal to $\sin^5 x$; at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\sin^5 x = 1$, but the expression $\frac{\sin x - \sin^2 x \cos(2x) + \sin x \cos^2(2x)}{4}$ equals $\frac{1 - 1(-1) + 1(-1)^2}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: +1. While this handles the OP's confusion, it should noted that, if the ultimate goal is "to express it in terms containing only first powers of sine and cosine", then there's a little more work to do. Specifically, the second-power term $\cos^2(2x)$ in the "answer" should be written in terms of the first power of $\cos(4x)$.

Comment: @Blue I agree, but I mainly intended to respond to his answer. However, I'll make an edit to give the fully simplified answer.